# How to apply a half circle mask to an image and add a button inside an image in ReactJS using ant design?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, antd

I want to create a half circle mask to an image, and have a button with camera icon in the center of this mask, but I'm struggling find a way to do it, my approach is create a circle image at the same place of the photo, then clip the circle to bottom half.

Can someone suggest me a better way to do it ? and how to place a button inside an image ?

I am using ReactJs and ant Design. Thanks for your time.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a over lay and set it half circle then fix it posotion absolute
here is my exmaple code

```css
.custom-avt {
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  width:200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 108px;
  width:200px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100px;
}

  button {
    width:100px;
    height: 20px;
  }
```

```html
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" class="custom-avt">
  <div class="overlay">
    <button>CAMERA</button>
  </div>
</img>
```

regularly!